# CSS-only design for hashed border

Tags: css

Is it possible to do a design like this (the bordered edges) without using images, but using CSS only..?

One of our designers has fired it to me and I think it might be a photoshop border, but I want to avoid using an image if possible.

[image: example of the border I want to recreate]

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: you mean "without using images, but using CSS only"

Comment: Yes without using images.

At the moment Nathan I have been using dashed  border but can't get the lines horizontally correct.

For example http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/stitched-look/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

Comment: I think the use of border.png prevents that from being a correct answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can! with the amazing [css3 patterns](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#)

And this is a rough [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uUmwN/6/) for you.

HTML:

```
<div class='pat-ho' ></div>
<div class='pat-ve' ></div>
<div class='text' >Text Text Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .pat-ho {
        position: absolute;
        width:500px; height:500px;
        background-color: gray;
        background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 50%);
        background-size: 20px 20px;
    }
    .pat-ve {
        position: absolute;
        width:450px; height:500px;
        background-color: gray;
        background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 50%);
        background-size: 20px 20px;
        left: 25px
    }
    .text {
        position: absolute;
        width: 470px;
        height: 470px;
        background: white;
        top: 25px; left: 25px;
    }
```

**Update:** And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/austinpray/fLdUD/) is a more accurate demo by [Austin Pray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1585343/austin-pray).

Comment: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#tablecloth - that might be also good pattern for your need. anyway the technique stays the same.

Comment: expanded on your demo a bit just for fun. http://jsfiddle.net/austinpray/fLdUD/

One div :0

Comment: You have strange definition for 'fun' indeed. Good job!

Comment: Thanks very much for this guys, it's just what I needed. Great responses as usual.

Answer (score 1):

With images only for frame, you could play around with this code: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WgBE8/)**

```
#frame
{
   border: 20px;
   border-image: url("http://ohhs.ohsd.net/~brick/sci/images/20_20.gif") 27 round stretch;
   border-image-width: 15px; 
   background-color:lightgray;
}
```